# Using XOAuth2 with NodeMailer and GMail (refresh-token)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been attempting to integrate NodeMailer into my project and I don't want to leave my Google account open using the "Less Secure App" way. I looked into XOAuth2 and I followed a tutorial for how to use the Google Developer's Console to create the client-id and the client-secret. Unfortunately, the tutorial was PHP oriented, so I was unable to continue from there. The XOAuth2 generator requires a client-id, a client-secret, and a refresh-token, but I am unsure how to get that last part.

I'm using this module in order to send a message from a GMail account to the user's supplied address. I was able to get it a test to work after enabling the "Less Secure App" setting, so I know what I've written so far is correct. It's just that I can't properly use XOAuth2 without the refresh-token.

Any help is appreciated.